# react-markdown images not rendering in browser

Tags: reactjs, markdown

I'm using react-markdown in a web app. When I load an image stored in the same folder as the .md file using `![](image1.jpg)` I get the image rendered correctly in the preview in Visual Studio, but not in the browser - instead I get an image error in both the development and production version. I've tried escaping HTML  and this doesn't work either. I'm loading a .md page as a component in  and all text and formatting works perfectly.

Thanks

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: No I didn't, I ended up just rendering the images below and outside the markdown component, instead of inline

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer! As you've probably guess, I was experiencing the same problem. The cause of the problem is in fact simple and I found it by asking myself this question: what is the difference between my md file read by the editor and what I see in my browser?

In React, your code is compiled: the image is just not found. For example, if you use create-react-app, the basic configuration allow you to import images like this: `import myImage from 'path/to/image.png'`. In your md file, if you use the image path then the compiler can't find it.

Are you using create-react-app?

Comment: @Sylla thanks and sorry for the late response. Yes I'm using create-react-app. So I import the image as a component in the main .js, then how do I call the component in the .md file?

Comment: Unfortunately the solution is not that straightforward, if you want to modify the way you use an image, you have to [eject](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#npm-run-eject). I had found another solution but I can't find the link anymore...

To allow server side rendering, I finally chose to use [Next.js](https://github.com/zeit/next.js) along with [MDX](https://github.com/mdx-js/mdx) and this is working very well!

Answer (score 19):

I kind of had the same issue with Strapi and Gatsby, watch this video it might help to fix the image URI to load the image correctly:
https://youtu.be/LIrK5KxsUSE?t=351

This is what fixed mine:

```
 <Reactmarkdown
  source={data.strapiArticle.content}
  transformImageUri={uri =>
    uri.startsWith("http") ? uri : `${process.env.REACT_IMAGE_BASE_URL}${uri}`
  }
/>
```

.env.development file:

```
REACT_IMAGE_BASE_URL =http://localhost:1337
```

Comment: REACT_IMAGE_BASE_URL doesn't work for me. Only if REACT_APP_IMAGE_BASE_URL then it works. And how to add domain name dynamically?

Answer (score 2):

Install rehype-raw to your project

```
npm install rehype-raw
```

Import rehypeRaw

```
import rehypeRaw from 'rehype-raw'
```

Add rehypePlugins props on your component

```
<ReactMarkdown remarkPlugins={[[remarkGfm,]]} children={readmeContent} rehypePlugins={[rehypeRaw]} />
```

Answer (score 1):

On issues page of react-markdown I found [an issue](https://github.com/remarkjs/react-markdown/issues/138), where a guy solved this by adding `escapeHtml={false}` to `<ReactMarkdown />` component. I tried it and it worked.